# Equalising divs via script - onload vs ondocumentready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't seem to get this working, tested on latest chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/kpqrzacy/

**CSS:**

```
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    color: #fff;
}
.col.left {
    background-color: red;
}
.col.right {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**JS (jquery)**

```
$(window).load(function() { //document ready will not consider images, so we keep window.load.
    function resetHeight() {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        $(".equal-height").height("auto").each(function() {
            maxHeight = $(this).height() > maxHeight ? $(this).height() : maxHeight;
        }).height(maxHeight);
    }
    resetHeight();
    // reset height on windows's resize so that the text doesn't overflow'
    $(window).resize(function() {
        resetHeight();
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col left equal-height">
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col right equal-height">
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
    </div>
```

*Is there perhaps a better way to equal height via javascript? Perhaps a script that is famous but am I not aware of?*

**UPDATE:**
If I change on the fiddle an option from *"onload"* to *"ondomready"* it seems to work.
**Why?**

Please advice

Comment: From what i can guess: load is triggered when window is created, subelement may not be ready at this stage. 
domready ensure that every elements are fully created (with property and subcontent initialized)

Comment: you are trying to set height on window load and your divs are not created that time.you should call the function on ready. change `$(window).load(` to `$(document).ready(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS only with display flex: http://jsfiddle.net/45syw9h1/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col left equal-height">
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
            <p>lorem ipsium</p>
            <p>lorem ipsium</p>
            <p>lorem ipsium</p>
            <p>lorem ipsium</p>
            <p>lorem ipsium</p>
            <p>lorem ipsium</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col right equal-height"> 
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>    
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>    
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
    </div>
</div>

.container{
    display: flex;
}

.col {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    color: #fff;
}

.col.left {
    background-color: red;
}

.col.right {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code as your answer. What makes your answer "work"?

Comment: @epuigvros - what if we have something more complex, such as this? Will flex behave? The yellow block should follow until the end of the blue block. http://jsfiddle.net/dm5x6mon/

Comment: @MEM Can't see a yellow block in your example. This link explains how flex works: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @MEM Also note that some old browsers will not support this

Comment: If at least ie9 could support that. Oh well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MEM Maybe there is another way to do it without display flex, I'm not sure, but it won't be as easy as this I guess.

Comment: Take care with `flexbox` because the support is not very important : [caniuse#flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). Maybe `table-cell` could be an other good option too and with larger support [caniuse#table-cell](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell)

Answer (score 1):

Already on Window Load in jsfiddle

If you set `Frameworks & Extensions` to `No wrap - in <body>` (default is `onLoad`) it works :

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/ogu5rhaj/

Comment: Do you know why and what is "no wrap -in body" - what do that mean? Thanks.

Comment: It means, your JS code will be encapsulated in `window.onload=function(){/*Your code*/}` (_option 1, default_), in `domReady` (_option 2_) like with jQuery `$(document).ready(function(){/*Your code*/});`, in a `<script></script>` tag in `<head>` (_option 3_) or in a `<script></script>` tag at the end of `<body>` (_option 4_).